# Is the example below considered efficient? And if not, how so can it be better?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I am new to programming and object-oriented programming.

**Below is a portion of the code in python that is running just fine as intended.** I have hard-coded some variable for testing purposes at the open_bank_account().

**Question: Would be considered fairly optimal and efficient? If not, where can I look to improve the code?**

```
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self, account_id, account_pin, account_balance):
        self._account_id = account_id
        self._account_pin = account_pin
        self._account_balance = account_balance
        self._individual_bank_account_dicitionary = {}
        self._individual_bank_account_dicitionary[account_id] = {"Pin": account_pin, "Balance": account_balance}

    def get_bank_account_balance(self, account_id):
        return "Balance: ${:.2f}".format(self._individual_bank_account_dicitionary[account_id]["Balance"])

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self._individual_bank_account_dicitionary)

class Bank:
    def __init__(self, bank_name):
        self._bank_name = bank_name
        self._bank_dicitionary = {}

    def update_bank_dictionary(self, bank_account):
        self._bank_dicitionary[bank_account._account_id] = {"Pin": bank_account._account_pin, "Balance": bank_account._account_balance}

    # 1. A method to return the dictionary of bank accounts of the object from class Bank.
    # 2. In this case, only bank_1 from main() is the object argument.      
    def get_bank_dictionary(self):
        return self._bank_dicitionary

    # 1. Method to create object bank_account only when needed.
    def get_bank_account(self, account_id):
        account_pin = self._bank_dicitionary[account_id]["Pin"]
        account_balance = self._bank_dicitionary[account_id]["Balance"]
        bank_account = Bank_Account(account_id, account_pin, account_balance)
        return bank_account

    # 1. This is used to convert the dictionary into a string for printing purposes.
    def string_bank_dictionary(self):
        string_list = ["account ID: {} \naccount Pin: {} \nBank Balance: {} \n".format(key, self._bank_dicitionary[key]["Pin"], self._bank_dicitionary[key]["Balance"])\
                      for key, value in self._bank_dicitionary.items()]
        return "\n".join(string_list) 

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.string_bank_dictionary())

def open_bank_account(bank):
#     # Uncomment out when running actual program.
#     account_id = input("Enter account id here: ")
#     account_pin = input("Enter account pin here: ")
#     account_balance = input("Enter account initial balance here: ")

    # Comment out when running actual program. 
    # Currently in used for testing purposes.
    account_id = 455
    account_pin = 123
    account_balance = 888
    bank_account = Bank_Account(account_id, account_pin, account_balance)
    bank.update_bank_dictionary(bank_account)

    # Comment out when running actual program.
    # Currently in used for testing purposes.
    account_id = 777
    account_pin = 777
    account_balance = 1
    bank_account = Bank_Account(account_id, account_pin, account_balance)
    bank.update_bank_dictionary(bank_account)

    # Comment out when running actual program. 
    # Currently in used for testing purposes.   
    account_id = 631
    account_pin = 222
    account_balance = 50
    bank_account = Bank_Account(account_id, account_pin, account_balance)
    bank.update_bank_dictionary(bank_account)

    return bank

def check_bank_blanance(bank):
    valid_id_password = False
    temporary_dictionary = bank.get_bank_dictionary()
    while True:
        account_id = int(input("Enter account id here: "))
        account_pin = int(input("Enter account pin here: "))
        for key in temporary_dictionary.keys():
            if account_id == key and temporary_dictionary[account_id]["Pin"] == account_pin:
                valid_id_password = True
                bank_account = bank.get_bank_account(account_id)
                print(bank_account.get_bank_account_balance(account_id))
                break
        if valid_id_password == True:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid account id/password. Please try again.")

def main():
    bank_1 = Bank("ABC Bank")
    while True:
        print("Menu \n1. Open bank account \n2. Check balance")
        while True:
            account_choice = int(input("Enter option here: "))
            if account_choice <= 0 and account_choice >= 7:
                account_choice = int(input("Enter option here: "))
            else:
                break        
        if account_choice == 6:
            break
        elif account_choice == 1:
            bank_1 = open_bank_account(bank_1)
        elif account_choice == 2:
            balance = check_bank_blanance(bank_1)

main()
```

The program works just fine. I would like to seek pointers on improvement if I code this better and more efficiently.

I have designed and kept only one object in the main(); i.e. bank_1; this contains a dictionary of the multiple bank account information. I have elected to only create the object bank_account at the open_bank_account() and check_bank_blanance() only when needed and these objects disappear once the function is done.

**The intention here is to keep as little objects available as possible at the main().**

No errors encountered. The program runs just fine; just enter <1>, then enter <2>, then enter <777> followed by <777>. It will print the bank account balance of $1.00 of the account id 777.

Comment: This will be more suitable platform for your question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ParthS007 thanks for pointing to me the right place to go. Thanks!

Comment: One of the main benefits of dictionaries is O(1) lookup of keys so instead looping over the keys just use something like `if account_id in temp_dict and temp_dict[account_id]["pin"] == pin:`